QGIS crashes when trying to create a new layout
I'm trying to create a new print layout but qgis keeps crashing. I have qgis 3.28 but also tried the newest version - this also crashed. I have a MacBook and have used qgis on this computer for several years and have never had a problem. Does anyone know how to work around this/what is wrong?

Have you tried with an empty project? Have your tried with a fresh installation? Have you tried with a default profile? Have you checked bug reports?

I tried with an empty project, it worked once but then it kept crashing. I tried installing the newest version with the same problem. I have not tried with a default profile or checked bug reports (don't know how/where to do these things but will have a look).

In the case of Windows a reinstall or upgrade install doesn't change the user profile, which is a typical recommended solution to your problem.  Perhaps there is a Mac equivalent.  Also in Windows, the OSGeo4W install goes into a different folder than a download of the binaries, so you can have two versions of the program on the computer.  I assume you could dosomething like that on a MacOS and if the newer install works either keep it or use that info to try to change the other one, or wipe it out entirely before a new install.
